# I am loading JSON data from a file. then trying to decode one of the value corresponding to a Key

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting error in below line

```
for i in split_json:
        read_values = json.loads(i + "]",strict = False)
```

split_json has the data in format

```
[[{"Key1":"Value1"},
[{"Key2":"Value2"}]
```

The value starts with a `'['` but  doesn't end with `']'`. So I am padding `']'` while calling `json.loads()`.

I am getting this error in the code mentioned above. My dataframe is correct.

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Comment: You are missing another closing bracket `]` at the first item

Comment: @palvarez I am using "]" while loading the json. so that cancels out the need.

Comment: This seems very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You have to fix the json you are reading, or even better: not split the json in the first place and use a single `json.loads` call. Can you explain the need for the splitting?

Answer (score 1):

You give your input as:

`[[{"Key1":"Value1"}, [{"Key2":"Value2"}]`

and say you are padding by one `]` however there are actually two mistakes in that JSON object, the correct object either looks like this:

`[[{"Key1":"Value1"}], [{"Key2":"Value2"}]]`

(adding one `]` after the `"Value1"}` and the other at the very end)

or looks like this:

`[[{"Key1":"Value1"}, {"Key2":"Value2"}]]`

(removing the `[` before `{"Key2"` and adding one at the very end)